# How do I correctly use generics?

Tags: java, android, json, generics

I basically am making webrequests and recieving a JSON response.  Depending on the request, I am parsing JSON request into objects I have created.  The parsing is pretty much the same no matter what the object Im parsing into looks like.  So I have a bunch of methods doing the same work only with different objects, I was wondering how I could accomplish this with generics?  Here is an example

```
   public static ArrayList<Contact> parseStuff(String responseData) {
ArrayList<Person> People = new ArrayList<Person>();
try {

    JSONArray jsonPeople = new JSONArray(responseData);
    if (!jsonPeople.isNull(0)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonPeople.length(); i++) {
            People.add(new Person(jsonPeople.getJSONObject(i)));
        }

    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {

}

return People;
```

}

Comment: You probably don't want to use generics. How many different objects are you parsing? is the code to parse each object identical?

Comment: Yes the code is basically identical except the object differs, so in the example i posted, I have the exact same method except you can replace the Contact object with a person object

Comment: How many different class types do you need to return.

Comment: Each time I run this method, only one class type will be returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [Effective Java 2, Item 29: *Consider typesafe heterogeneous type containers*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=effective+java+heterogeneous+type&source=bl&ots=yXLiNgo6T0&sig=t035r7WbwAGmJqGaUOEMRnWGKkU&hl=en&ei=N5QZTffhDoSq8AbogJnKDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The basic idea is that you could imagine you have some `Deserializer` interface. Then you can have a `Map<Class<?>, Deserializer<String, Object>>`. The map is basically a registry from type to the proper `Deserializer` for that type (which deserializes from a String (perhaps you want a json type or something instead of String, but String works) to the type of interest.

The real trick is that *you must enforce* that the class key type matches the deserializer type. i.e. - For some Class that is a key in the map, you have a Deserializer as a value. You can do this with a generic method. For example:

```
<T> void put(Class<T> clazz, Deserializer<String, T> deserializer) {
  map.put(clazz, deserializer);
}
```

Then to use the heterogeneous map, you can use a generic method again:

```
<T> T deserialize(Class<T> typeToDeserializeFromJson, String toDeserialize) {
  return typeToDeserializeFromJson.cast(
      deserializers.get(tTDFJ).deserialize(toDeserialize));
}
```

You use the type that is specified by the method caller to

- lookup the right `Deserializer`

  deserialize the json text to an `Object`

  safely cast the `Object` to the right type which we know is safe because of how we constructed the map in the first place.

I hope what I said was at least somewhat clear. Reading the corresponding entry in EJ2 should help!

***UPDATE:***

[As Abhinav points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544191/how-do-i-correctly-use-generics/4544641#4544641), the GSON library will help you accomplish your final goal of deserializing objects in a way that uses generics appropriately. However, I think your question is more about generics than the end goal so I feel my answer is more appropriate. GSON must be implemented using a heterogeneous type container :-).

Thanks, [Abhinav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526635/abhinav) for pointing out GSON!

Comment: Perhaps the example would be more clear if I got rid of the `String` type for `Deserializer`. My intention is that a `Deserializer<F, T>` will deserialize an object of type F to an object of type T.

Comment: How would you do this if you had a heterogeneous container? How GSON can know which deserialized to use? Can you set it to look into properties to decide?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) instead of JSON. It really simplifies your life.

Comment: gson must be implemented in a way similar to what I suggest. (A typesafe heterogeneous container is necessary and specifying the type when calling the deserialization method is also necessary).

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if there will be concerns depending on gson since this is tagged as Android.

Comment: Gson takes care of internals for you. You just need to say something like - "(new Gson()).fromJson(numbersText, PhoneStatus.class)".

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work with Android -- I'm saying that people developing mobile apps sometimes shy away from third party libraries when they are easy to avoid. Although from my quick glance it doesn't seem too heavyweight.

Comment: Yeah, it is sometimes a pity when devs are too reluctant -- org.json package specifically is so primitive that using a proper JSON library (Gson, Jackson, json-lib) would simplify life a lot for most cases.